# How to setup /.well-known/assetlinks.json on Google AppEngine Web App (Java)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, web-applications, applinks

I need to include the **.well-known/assetlinks.json** file in my AppEngine Web App. It is mandatory to enable App Links for my Android application as described here https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/index.html

I added this line in the appengine-web.xml file

```
<static-files>
    <include path=".well-known/assetlinks.json"/>
</static-files>
```

The problem is that it works in local

http://localhost:8384/.well-known/assetlinks.json

but not when I deploy the web app and it returns a **404 error**.

http://www.example.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json

I suppose it could be a security restriction but I looked everywhere in the Google Cloud Platform Console and I didn't find anything about.

Someone have a solution to this problem?
Thank you

Comment: It would appear that it's currently not possible to use static folders starting with a . in App Engine.

Comment: I've added a more generic solution to this problem here http://stackoverflow.com/a/44023751/654070

Comment: If the server stores Public Certificate information, or Oauth information in the .well-known folder, REMOVING THE DOT from the .well-known folder will BREAK your OAuth/OIDC and anything else referencing assets in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've encountered something similar, albeit with the python runtime.

This usually occurs during the upload/deployment of the app engine app where the correct MIME type cannot be accurately guessed. The file ends up being deployed as a regular binary file, `application/octect`(or not at all?). You can confirm if this is the case from your deployment logs.

If so, you'll have to supply a [MIME type](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref#mime_types_for_static_files) for `json` in the `web.xml` file

```
<mime-mapping>
  <extension>json</extension>
  <mime-type>application/json</mime-type>
</mime-mapping>
```

Comment: Sorry I added the static-files node in the appengine-web.xml not in the web.xml and it doesn't work

Comment: The problem is the starting dot

Answer (score 0):

`<static-files>` and `<mime-mapping>` need to go in **appengine-web.xml**, not web.xml. Refer to the doc '[appengine-web.xml Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appref#include_exclude)' for details.

Comment: Sorry I added the static-files node in the appengine-web.xml not in the web.xml and it doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

Still, the MIME type associations get set in web.xml, as stated on the mentioned page, at the “MIME types for static files” paragraph: “By default, static files are served using a MIME type selected based on the filename extension. You can associate custom MIME types with filename extensions for static files in web.xml using  elements.”

Answer (score 0):

AppEngine doesn't like the `.` at the start of the directory name (I tried a few combinations in the **appengine-web.xml** file, even `<include path="**assetlinks.json" expiration="365d" />` with no luck).  Interestly, it works fine when running on the dev server (Eclipse + Windows 10).  It's only when you deploy it, does it fail.

The solution was to remove the `.` from the directory, and create a servlet that reads it.  Then in your **web.xml**, map the servlet with the `.`.  As described here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/44023751/418057

Answer (score -1):

**Ok I found a solution by myself!**

in appengine-web.xml use this configuration

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Assetlinks</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>api.servlets.WorkAroundHttpServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Assetlinks</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/.well-known/assetlinks.json</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

and create a class WorkAroundHttpServlet that extends HttpServlet

```
public class WorkAroundHttpServlet extends HttpServlet
{
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException
    {

        if (!req.getRequestURI().startsWith("/.well-known/assetlinks.json"))
        {
            resp.sendError(404);
            return;
        }

            File file= new File(getServletContext().getRealPath("/") +  "/assetlinks.json");

            resp.setContentType("application/json");
            resp.getOutputStream().print(FileUtils.readFileToString(file, "utf-8")); 
    }
}
```